# Excel VBA Find function oddity

Tags: excel, vba

**In Short**

- I am searching a single column range for "psiTimBeamLabel1"
- For some reason, Vba's .Find function is finding "psiTimBeamLabel10" as a match.

**Background**

I am searching a named range (rngCellsList) which is a single column of cells. In the instance where this is failing - the value I am looking for is "psiTimBeamLabel1" This item appears several times in the list. I have some processing that occurs each time it is found in the list. My code paraphrases to the following:

```
Set rngCell = rngCellsList.Find("psiTimBeamLabel1")
strFoundCellAddr = rngCell.Address

Do 

   ... some processing

   Set rngCell = rngCellList.Find("psiTimBeamLabel1",rngCell)

Loop Until rngCell is Nothing or rngCell.Address = strFoundCellAddr
```

Basically

1. Search the range to find the first instance of the string
2. Note the address of that first instance
3. Start a loop and do some processing
4. Before the end of the loop - do another search, staring at the most recent found location
5. Loop until either Not Found, or the only instance is the first found location

This has worked fine until now. There are several other instances where there are multiples in the list and my logic has worked previously.

In this particular case I have several instances of "psiTimBeamLabel1" in the list. But I also have a couple of "psiTimBeamLabel10" - and for some reason when searching for "psiTimBeamLabel1" the look is .Find ing "psiTimBeamLabel10"

Any idea why or how I can get around this?

Thanks, Ken

Comment: You have to search the whole cell contents otherwise that will match.

Comment: Try changing of `rngCellList.Find("psiTimBeamLabel1",rngCell)` withh `rngCellList.Find(What:="psiTimBeamLabel1", After:=rngCell, LookAt:=xlWhole`.

Comment: Find() remembers parameters from the last time it was used, so you should always include *at least* the `lookIn` and `lookAt` parameters when using it in VBA.

Comment: Damn. Of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `For..Each` instead, because the `Like` operator allows you to use negative wildcards.

```
For Each rngCell in rngCellsList
If rngCell Like "psiTimBeamLabel1[!0-9]" Then ...
Next rngCell
```

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find (Remarks)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator